# Create a dictionary with 2 or more variables as keys to values with a unique ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to **create a `dictionary` where I want to have a customer name & some other detail mapped to a unique value ID**. The method I'm using currently using gets more confusing as I progress. **Wanted to know if there's any concise `dictionary method` to use.**

```
a=1,2,3,4,5
b="a,b,c,d,e"
b2=tuple(b.split(","))
c=12,34,45,56,78

tuple_a=tuple(zip(a,b2)) # create a match with a & b as tuple_a
directory=dict(zip(tuple_a,c)) # create match with tuple_a & c as directory

# thus have successfully mapped 3 variables into a single dictionary.

def see_directory(z):
    print(z)
    for x,y in z:
        print(y,x,z[x,y])

see_directory(directory)
```

As you can see I use the above code for 2 variables. But if want to add a 3rd variable it becomes more confusing

I tried mapping `tuples` to `dictionary`, but all values are mapped to a single Value. which doesn't serve the purpose.

```
IN[]:
    directory_2=dict()
    
    directory_2[a,b2]=c
    print(directory_2)
OUT[]:
{((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')): (12, 34, 45, 56, 78)} #doesn't solve the purpose
```

expected output:

```
{(1, 'a'): 12, (2, 'b'): 34, (3, 'c'): 45, (4, 'd'): 56, (5, 'e'): 78}
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: It would be helpful to show an example of the output you want.

Comment: `{(1, 'a'): 12, (2, 'b'): 34, (3, 'c'): 45, (4, 'd'): 56, (5, 'e'): 78}` is precisely what I get when I run your code. That looks like the expected output.

Comment: ```{(x,y) : z for x,y,z in zip(a, b.split(","), c)}``` ?

Comment: @Mark Meyer. Yes,but i want know if any other method can be used. If want to map {(a,b,c): d}. the above code becomes even more confusing. 

Plus used **a,b,c for simple reference**. Can be used differently in diff. programs. **What I want is to make a dictionary with `{(a,b,c):d}` or more add more keys if required.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to manage arbitrary numbers of components for your dict keys, you can put them all in a list. Then as you add components to the keys, the code doesn't get more complex, it just adds a member to that list. For example:

```
keys = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    "a,b,c,d,e".split(","),
    'x,y,z,p,q'.split(",")
]

values = 12,34,45,56,78

directory = dict(zip(zip(*keys), values))
```

**directory is:**

```
{(1, 'a', 'x'): 12,
 (2, 'b', 'y'): 34,
 (3, 'c', 'z'): 45,
 (4, 'd', 'p'): 56,
 (5, 'e', 'q'): 78}
```

Another key component, even a generated one? No problem, just one more line:

```
keys = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    "a,b,c,d,e".split(","),
    'x,y,z,p,q'.split(","),
    (f'a-{i}' for i in range(5))
]

values = 12,34,45,56,78

directory = dict(zip(zip(*keys), values))
```

=>

```
{(1, 'a', 'x', 'a-0'): 12,
 (2, 'b', 'y', 'a-1'): 34,
 (3, 'c', 'z', 'a-2'): 45,
 (4, 'd', 'p', 'a-3'): 56,
 (5, 'e', 'q', 'a-4'): 78}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot